# How to stop ec2 instance using lambda if there is no objects in the folder/ of s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

basically i tried lambda function and s3 "All object delete event" trigger but it's stopping the instance even if i delete one file from the given folder of bucket. whenever a object gets deleted from the s3 bucket dump/ directory the following function stop the instance, but what i want is it should only stop if there is no file left in the dump/ directory.

```
import boto3
region = 'us-west-1'
instances = ['i-12345cb6de4f78g9h']
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ec2.stop_instances(InstanceIds=instances)
    print('stopped your instances: ' + str(instances))
```

Comment: You may need to think other way. Poller which checks if the bucket is empty and then shutdown the VM.

Comment: What is a S3 "deleteallfiles" trigger?

Comment: Sorry, but your question is unclear. Please Edit your question to provide more information. For example, tell us how your AWS Lambda function is being triggered and show us the code of your Lambda function.

Comment: updated question with code please check it. @JohnRotenstein

Answer (score 1):

There is no trigger from S3 to Lambda that is "empty bucket".  The [S3 triggers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/NotificationHowTo.html) are:

- New object created events
- Object removal events
- Restore object events
- Reduced Redundancy Storage
- Replication events

The closest is `s3:ObjectRemoved:Delete` or  `s3:ObjectRemoved:DeleteMarkerCreated`.  Your code will have to do the work to see if the bucket is now empty when you get the Delete trigger.  If the bucket is empty **then** stop the EC2.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have configured Amazon S3 to trigger your AWS Lambda function for **All object delete events**. This means that the Lambda function will be triggered whenever *any* object is deleted in the bucket (for a given Prefix, if defined).

Since you only wish to Stop the EC2 instance **when the bucket is empty**, you will need to add code to your Lambda function that determines whether the bucket is empty. If it *is* empty, it should then Stop the instance.

The function can do this by listing the contents of the bucket. If no objects are returned in the listing, then it will know that the bucket is empty.

**Alternative method**

I am assuming that you have code running on the EC2 instance that processes objects from the Amazon S3 bucket and then deletes the object once it is processed. Therefore, after deleting the object, your code on the EC2 instance could just as easily check the contents of the S3 bucket and, if there are no more objects, it could stop the instance itself (without having to use an AWS Lambda function). This can be done by either calling `StopInstances()`, or by simply telling the Operating System to Shutdown (eg `sudo shutdown now -h`). This will then stop the instance. (Make sure you include `-h` to halt the machine.)

Or, you could totally change your architecture to feed information to the EC2 instance via an Amazon SQS queue rather than using files in an Amazon S3 bucket.

See: [Auto-Stop EC2 instances when they finish a task - DEV Community](https://dev.to/aws/auto-stop-ec2-instances-when-they-finish-a-task-2f0i)

Comment: alright thanks for help i will try this.

Answer (score 0):

Why not checking the content of the bucket, if there is no object then stop the instance. May use code like below

```
    import boto3
    region = 'us-west-1'
    instances = ['i-12345cb6de4f78g9h']
    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)

    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

    def lambda_handler(event, context):
            # get the bucket and a list of all objects
            bucket  = s3.Bucket('bucket_name')
            count_obj = 0
                            for i in bucket.objects.all():
                               count_obj = count_obj + 1
            
            # check bucket object length, stop instance if there is no object
            if count_obj == 0:
                ec2.stop_instances(InstanceIds=instances)
                print('stopped your instances: ' + str(instances))
```

Comment: tried this code but its giving this error "errorMessage": "object of type 's3.Bucket.objectsCollection' has no len()"

Comment: Iterate through objects to check the count, updated my answer, check now, inside the loop you can apply folder check also

Comment: yes tried this and loop also with bucket.objects.filter(Delimiter='/', Prefix='dump/'): code is running but its not effecting instance state even if i have files or no files in dump folder. basically if statement not executing i think.

Comment: Print count_obj to check the value

Comment: showing the number of objects if i print that,loop is working but issue is with instance state if i delete all files from bucket its supposed to stop instance when i run it again as in the if statement but its not effecting the instance state it's still running. btw thanks for help i appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not something that can be easily triggered using an event notification. You can run a cloud watch event and **schedule your Lambda** function to run after every hour for example. Within the Lambda, you can check whether your S3 bucket is empty or not. If it's empty, you can turn off your Ec2 instance.

This medium guide is doing something similar: https://medium.com/geekculture/terraform-setup-for-automatically-turning-off-ec2-instances-upon-inactivity-d7f414390800